# Creating a custom datagridrowview

Tags: .net, winforms, datagridview

I'm trying to create a custom gridview similar to the one present in SQL Management Studio for mapping fields to another database.
[alt text http://img5.imageshack.us/img5/5183/columnmappingsdg5.png](http://img5.imageshack.us/img5/5183/columnmappingsdg5.png)

I tried to create a custom datagridviewrow with custom cellviews with controls inside and all I get are empty cells inside.

[alt text http://img9.imageshack.us/img9/8890/testedexampleeg7.png](http://img9.imageshack.us/img9/8890/testedexampleeg7.png)

Does anyone have a good idea how I can get this working. I've looked at other posts and I don't think they apply in this case.

Comment: To what are you binding the DataGridView? (DataTable, Collection)?  Also, when you mention custom cells, what do you mean? Are you trying to add combo boxes?

Comment: There is no binding in the traditional sense. I have a collection of column names and I create the row for each item. Each row has a checkbox column, name column and a combobox with the destination. I just need to iterate through the datagrid to find which columns get used and where they go to.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misunderstanding your question, this can be easily done in either design time or in runtime, but instead of adding rows, you got to define the *columns* as the ones with the control type:

- In design time, just drag a DataGridView control to your form.
- Right click the grid, then click on "Add Column"
- Select "Unbound column"
- In the Type combobox, select the type of column. You can pick checkbox, comobobox, text, image...
- Click "Add", repeat as you need.

Now, if you need to do it in runtime, just do something like this in a form with a datagridview:

```vb
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    'Define the new columns

    Dim colCheck As New DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn
    Dim colText As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
    Dim colCombo As New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn

    '...etc, also available are DataGridViewImageColumn, DataGridViewButtonColumn, DataGridViewLinkColumn

    'Change the column properties as you need

    colCheck.HeaderText = "Header Text"
    colCheck.Width = 300

    'Add the columns to the grid 

    Me.DataGridView1.Columns.Add(colCheck)
    Me.DataGridView1.Columns.Add(colText)
    Me.DataGridView1.Columns.Add(colCombo)
End Sub
```